# TortoiseHG: Folder showing unversion overlay although files inside have green check mark

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I created a local repo and added a folder into it
however, all the files in the folder appear with the green check mark
but the folder itself appears with the Unversion overlay (Blue question mark) on the folder icon

I am using TortoiseHG version 6.2.3, how can I get the folder to show the green check mark so that it can track any changes to the files inside it?

Comment: RMB on parent Folder - THG - "Update Icons"?